# Add an arbitrary element to an xrange()?

Tags: python, generator, xrange

In Python, it's more memory-efficient to use `xrange()` instead of `range` when iterating.

The trouble I'm having is that I want to iterate over a large list -- such that I need to use `xrange()` and after that I want to check an arbitrary element.

With `range()`, it's easy: `x = range(...) + [arbitrary element]`.

But with `xrange()`, there doesn't seem to be a cleaner solution than this:

```
for i in xrange(...):
    if foo(i):
        ...
if foo(arbitrary element):
        ...
```

Any suggestions for cleaner solutions? Is there a way to "append" an arbitrary element to a generator?

Comment: Can you clarify what kind of iteration you're doing? If you're iterating over a list itself using `xrange(len(my_list))` you shouldn't be using `xrange` at all, and can do this using `for i, elem in enumerate(my_list)` then check the value of i.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I am certainly not iterating over `len(my_list)`. I don't know why you would assume that. Without loss of generality, let's assume that I am iterating over a range sufficiently large to warrant using `xrange()` instead of `range()`, e.g. `xrange(99999999)`.

Comment: "I don't know why you would assume that." `range(len(x))` is a very common iteration anti-pattern in Python and appears on StackOverflow questions hundreds of times a day. Just wanted to clarify.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist fair enough. Sorry for the aggressive response.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) lets you make a combined iterator from multiple iterables without concatenating them (so no expensive temporaries):

```
from itertools import chain

# Must wrap arbitrary element in one-element tuple (or list)
for i in chain(xrange(...), (arbitrary_element,)):
    if foo(i):
        ...
```

Comment: Wow this is great to know.  itertools strikes again!

Answer (score 7):

I would recommend keeping the `arbitrary_element` check out of the loop, but if you want to make it part of the loop, you can use [`itertools.chain`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain):

```
for i in itertools.chain(xrange(...), [arbitrary_element]):
    ...
```

Comment: Damn I was late :D This is the true answer.

Comment: I disagree with the recommendation -- duplicating the contents of the loop is surely worse than chaining the ranges together.

Comment: @Hurkyl: You don't have to duplicate the loop body if you make it a function.

Comment: @user2357112: I don't disagree, but that's not what you (appear to have) recommended. (also, factoring the body out would obfuscate the code if it's sufficiently simple)

Comment: Putting it in the loop is plausible in this example given that `chain` is such a small operation with no extra memory used.